# Conseguir precisión con QVariant y valores numéricos en base de datos

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una lista de lista de QVariant para rellenar una tabla con el método `QVariant::data`

Para ello, lleno esta lista así:

```
consulta.exec(cadena_consulta);
QList<QList<QVariant>>datos;
QList<QVariant> lineaDatos;
while (consulta.next())
{
    for (int i=0;i<NUM_COLUMNAS;i++)
    {
          lineaDatos.append(consulta.value(i));
    }
 }
 datos.append(lineaDatos);
 lineaDatos.clear();
```

Luego el método *data* se limita a retornar el `QVariant` correspondiente:

```
if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
{
    return datos.at(indice.row()+1).at(indice.column());
}
return QVariant();
```

La idea que tengo es formatear la salida mediante delegados, más adelante.

Sin embargo veo que los valores numéricos pierden precisión, de forma que un número así
`700.2`
se transforma en 
`700.2000000000000005`

Pero es que si leo el valor con `qDebug()`, leo el valor correcto, aunque luego en la tabla se muestra el otro incorrecto.

Buscando dudas similares, veo que están orientadas a una pérdida de precisión al pasar de `QString` a `QVariant` o vicecersa, pero no es mi caso. 
En todo caso mi problema se da al pasar de un valor `numeric` (que se aloja como `Double` dentro del `QVariant`) de la base de datos a `QVariant`. También he visto una posible "solución", que sería la siguiente:

```
consulta.exec(cadena_consulta);
QList<QList<QVariant>>datos;
QList<QVariant> lineaDatos;
while (consulta.next())
{
    for (int i=0;i<NUM_COLUMNAS;i++)
    {
        if (consulta.value(i).type()==QVariant::Double)
        {
            float numero = consulta.value(i).toDouble();
            QString numeroletra = QString::number(numero, 'f', 2);
            lineaDatos.append(static_cast<QVariant>(numeroletra));
        }
        else
        {
            lineaDatos.append(consulta.value(i));
        }
    }
 }
 datos.append(lineaDatos);
 lineaDatos.clear();
```

Que en definitiva consiste que alojar el valor del `QVariant` a una variable `float`, luego construir un `QString` a partir de ese `float`, y por último hacer un casting del `QString` de nuevo a `QVariant` , lo cual me parece un absurdo, aunque funcione.

La pregunta es, ¿cómo evitar esa pérdida de precisión del QVariant?

Answer (score 0):

`float` tiene una precisión típica de 6 dígitos. Es decir, únicamente los 6 primeros dígitos son representativos. El resto se consideran basura. En el caso de `double` la cantidad de dígitos representativos aumenta a 12.

Esto implica, por ejemplo, que no puedes comprar dos `double` o `float` entre sí directamente, es decir, `if( a == b )` ya que los bits *basura* también se comparan, lo que provoca que, normalmente ciertas operaciones aparentemente *lógicas* generen resultados inesperados.

Las operaciones de comparación con números decimales deben hacerse con un margen de error a elegir dentro del rango válido (hasta `1e-6` para `float` y `1e-12` para `double`):

```
if( std::abs(a - b) < 1e-5 ) // if(a == b)

if( a + 1e-5 < b ) // if( a < b )
```

Pues bien, si los 12 dígitos de precisión que te ofrece *double* son lo suficientemente buenos para ti, deja las cosas como está y actualiza las funciones que comparen esos números.

Si, en cambio, necesitas una precisión absoluta y total, plantéate pasar los números a `int` o `long long`. Eso sí, antes tendrás que establecer un número fijo de decimales para cada número (si se usan dos decimales, `123.45` pasa a ser `12345`). El problema que tienes en este caso es que si te aparece un número con más decimales de los previstos perderás precisión.